# How to use PDFBOX with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, linux, pdf, pdfbox

I am using Ubuntu.I want to use PDFBOX with JavaScript.I want to open the pdf document in editable form on my web. I will use the HTML CSS for frontend design and JavaScript with pdf box to open pdf document in editable form.

How this can be possible if anyone have idea please share it.

I am using Ubuntu.
I tried by downloading a code from [github](https://github.com/rse/pdfbox-simple).

and then install the pdfbox-simple library

using the below command:

```
$ npm install pdfbox-simple
```

the library was installed
Then i goto sample.js file It contains the below code

```
(async () => {

const PDFBox = require("pdfbox-simple")
const pdfbox = new PDFBox()
await pdfbox.exec("PDFMerger", "foo.pdf", "bar.pdf", "quux.pdf")

})().catch((err) => {
   console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`)
})
```

Then Run the file by writing
node sample.js

but got no output not anything in console no new document was created anywhere

I don't know whats the issue this was the only code i got related to my issue

How this can be possible if anyone have idea please share it.